# Why does border not show with border-b? (tailwind)

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I have a div that I styled as below: (react code)

```
 <div className='w-full flex flex-row items-center border-blue-100 border-b'>
```

With this code the bottom border wouldn't show.
[image: No border between Borrower and Co-Borrower]The only way for the bottom border to show with 1px width is to add border-solid. However, adding border-solid means other border sides show up too:

[image: Borders showing on all other sides]

How can I style bottom border only?

Comment: The code supplied should give a bottom border as you were expecting: https://play.tailwindcss.com/n1sO4LC928. Check dev tools to see if there is a style overriding it.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is perfectly fine.

```
<div className='w-full flex flex-row items-center border-blue-100 border-b'>
```

l only changed the div className to class and the border showed up.

```
<div class='w-full flex flex-row items-center border-blue-100 border-b'>Borrower</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a same problem just hide other border with the background color

```
<div className="border-solid border-x-gray-400 border-t-gray-400">
```